# How to format text in a textarea

Tags: javascript, formatting, textarea, haml

I am adding some text by default to a textarea

```
%textarea.email_copy
    Hi <awesome friend>,

    I am using this site called XXXX, and you should check it out. It is for smart and thoughtful people to share about their experiences and ideas around topics they care about, and I think you are perfect for it.

    I generated a special invite for you:

    http://some_link

    <%= current_user.getFirstName() %>
```

However, when I look at the loaded page I see this

[image]

How can I add paragraphings or spacings between the paragraphs?

Comment: Are you building a spam engine?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon This is way to well written to be spam

Comment: @AlexisPigeon, no no, I am not building any engine here, in fact I am just asking users to copy and paste this email copy if they want to invite their friends to use the site. But I think adding a little formatting to this will help

Answer (score 2):

Check here: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/haml/

```
~ - Ruby expression preserving whitespace, e.g. %pre~ @content.body
  Works just like =, but calls the find_and_preserve helper to keep
  line breaks intact in the output.
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

A textarea cannot contain markup. If you want only presentation and no input, a div should do fine. If you want both presentation and input, you should look into a RTE.

Comment: I want the user to be able to easily copy and paste the text into their own email composer